# SKShapeNode has unbounded memory growth

Tags: memory-management, ios7, sprite-kit

If I run this code in a SKScene sublass init method

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

            SKShapeNode *shape = [SKShapeNode node];

            shape.antialiased = NO;

            CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

            CGPathAddEllipseInRect(path, NULL, CGRectMake(arc4random()%320, arc4random()%320, 10, 10));

            shape.path = path;

            [shape setStrokeColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

            CGPathRelease(path);

            [self addChild:shape];

            [shape removeFromParent];

        }
```

and everytime I run this code in my SKView controlling controller

```
SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;

// Create and configure the scene.

SKScene * scene = [ZTMyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];

scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;



// Present the scene.

[skView presentScene:scene];
```

my memory usage grow until the memory is full and crashes. This does not happen if I use a SKSpriteNode. Has anyone a fix for this?

Summary: I create the sprite kit template project, add a lot of SKShapeNodes and replace the old SKScene with a new one.

I added a sample project to github https://github.com/zeiteisen/MemoryTest

Comment: if you can isolate this in a minimal project and it verifies this behavior, then report it as a bug to Apple https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/using-bug-reporter/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I became aware of this issue while reading another post. I messed around with `SKShapeNode` a bit and indeed verified the memory leak issue pinpointed here.

While doing that, I had an idea...

Not really a new idea, more of a repurposed one. This wonderful idea actually allowed me to use SKShapeNodes to my hearts content :)

**POOLING**

Yep... I just created a pool of SKShapeNodes that I reused as needed. What a difference that makes :)

You simply redefine the path whenever needed, when done using return to your pool, and it'll be waiting there for you to play with again at a later time.

Create a ivar or property `NSMutableArray` in your `SKScene` called pool and create it when you init the `SKScene`. You can either populate the array with your shape nodes during init, or you can create them as needed.

This is something quick method I created for grabbing a new node from the pool :

```
-(SKShapeNode *)getShapeNode
{
    if (pool.count > 0)
    {
        SKShapeNode *shape = pool[0];
        [pool removeObject:shape];
        return shape;
    }

    // if there is not any nodes left in the pool, create a new one to return
    SKShapeNode *shape = [SKShapeNode node];

    return shape;
}
```

So wherever in the scene you need a SKShapeNode you'd do this :

```
SKShapeNode *shape = [self getShapeNode];
// do whatever you need to do with the instance
```

When you are done using the shape node, just return it to the pool and set the path to NULL, for example :

```
[pool addObject:shape];
[shape removeFromParent];
shape.path = NULL;
```

I know it's a workaround and not an ideal solution, but certainly this is a very viable workaround for anyone wanting to use a large number of SKShapeNodes and not bleed memory.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the shape, and straight after removing it, why?

```
[self addChild:shape];

[shape removeFromParent]
```

Comment: Presumably to demonstrate the problem he is experiencing in its simplest form.