# SKShapeNode bad Performance

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skshapenode

While learning and playing around with Swift and Spritekit i run into an issue:
I can´t seem to create many SKShapeNodes at Runtime.
I am trying to fill the Screen with "random" Triangles [image: Triangles on the Screen]

These brown-ish Triangles are SKShapeNodes created like this:

```
func createTwoFloorTrianglesAtLocation(xPos:CGFloat, yPos:CGFloat, width:CGFloat, height:CGFloat, orientation:Bool) -> [SKShapeNode] {
    
    let path1 = UIBezierPath()
    let path2 = UIBezierPath()
    
    if orientation {
        path1.move(to: CGPoint(x: xPos, y: yPos))
        path1.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: xPos, y: yPos + height))
        path1.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: xPos + width, y: yPos))
        
        path2.move(to: CGPoint(x: xPos + width, y: yPos))
        path2.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: xPos + width, y: yPos + height))
        path2.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: xPos, y: yPos + height))
    } else {
        path1.move(to: CGPoint(x: xPos, y: yPos))
        path1.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: xPos + width, y: yPos + height))
        path1.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: xPos, y: yPos + height))
        
        path2.move(to: CGPoint(x: xPos + width, y: yPos))
        path2.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: xPos, y: yPos))
        path2.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: xPos + width, y: yPos + height))
    }
    
    
    let triangle1 = SKShapeNode(path: path1.cgPath)
    triangle1.fillColor = groundColors[GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextInt(upperBound: groundColors.count)]!
    triangle1.name = "colorSprite"
    triangle1.lineWidth = 0.0
    
    let triangle2 = SKShapeNode(path: path2.cgPath)
    triangle2.fillColor = groundColors[GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextInt(upperBound: groundColors.count)]!
    triangle2.name = "colorSprite"
    triangle2.lineWidth = 0.0
    
    return [triangle1, triangle2]
}
```

I add these Triangles calling #addChild(SKNode) to the GameScene.

These Triangles don´t move or anything, they are supposed to disappear later in the Game by "drawing lines" above them.

The Problem is that i get very bad FPS and a high CPU-Usage as well as a high Power-Usage in both the XCode-Simulator and on a real Device (iPhone 13 Pro Max, too).
If i reduce the Amount of Triangles it gets better, but i´d like to not do that.

Is there any way to fix this issue?

I also read online ([Create an SKTexture from an SKShapeNode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23461966/create-an-sktexture-from-an-skshapenode)) that some use SKSpriteNode instead of SKShapeNode.
But if use the following code to "convert" my ShapeNodes to SpriteNodes before adding them as a Child to the Scene, i see the Node-Counter in the Bottom left is also around 1000ish but there are no Rectangles rendered.

```
func addNodesToParent(_ stuff:[SKShapeNode]) {
    for n in stuff {
        addChild(SKSpriteNode(texture: self.view?.texture(from: n)))
        //addChild(n)
    }
}
```

I hope someone has an idea that i can try.
Thanks in advance,

Greetings,
Nico

//Edit1:
Tried to use Arrays of CGPoints instead of CGPath, sadly it didn´t change anything in the Performance.
Code:

```
func createTwoFloorTrianglesAtLocation(xPos:CGFloat, yPos:CGFloat, width:CGFloat, height:CGFloat, orientation:Bool) -> [SKShapeNode] {
    var p1:[CGPoint]
    var p2:[CGPoint]
    
    if orientation {
        p1 = [CGPoint(x: xPos, y: yPos), CGPoint(x: xPos, y: yPos + height), CGPoint(x: xPos + width, y: yPos)]
        p2 = [CGPoint(x: xPos + width, y: yPos), CGPoint(x: xPos + width, y: yPos + height), CGPoint(x: xPos, y: yPos + height)]
        
    } else {
        p1 = [CGPoint(x: xPos, y: yPos), CGPoint(x: xPos + width, y: yPos + height), CGPoint(x: xPos, y: yPos + height)]
        p2 = [CGPoint(x: xPos + width, y: yPos), CGPoint(x: xPos, y: yPos), CGPoint(x: xPos + width, y: yPos + height)]
        
    }
    
    let triangle1 = SKShapeNode(points: &p1, count: p1.count)
    triangle1.fillColor = groundColors[GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextInt(upperBound: groundColors.count)]!
    triangle1.name = "colorSprite"
    triangle1.lineWidth = 0.0
    
    let triangle2 = SKShapeNode(points: &p2, count: p2.count)
    triangle2.fillColor = groundColors[GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextInt(upperBound: groundColors.count)]!
    triangle2.name = "colorSprite"
    triangle2.lineWidth = 0.0
    
    return [triangle1, triangle2]
}
```

Comment: Did you try to create triangles with points arrays instead of cgpath ?

Comment: Tried it right now, sadly not much of a Performance change (tried it just in the simulator now, but i don´t think it will differ too much from a real device). I updated my Post with the new Code in it, maybe i did something wrong?

Comment: Did you tried to have different name for each node ? Something like xpos_ypos_2.

Comment: Found interesting [article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/184/tips-to-optimize-your-spritekit-game). Especially part 4 (replace not blend) ,  5 : (remove nodes the player can’t see) and 8 (disabling sibling order)

Comment: So i tried basically everything you told/linked me, sadly nothing worked. But i think some stuff referenced in the Article doesn´t really fits my use-case, but nonetheless it didn´t change anything.

Answer (score 1):

SKShapeNodes are relatively expensive. your scene will definitely bog down when you have a lot of them. Render to Texture is a good approach. this reduces lots of SKShapeNodes (or labels or other graphical nodes) to a single SKTexture.

```
func renderToTexture() -> SKTexture? {
    let container:SKNode = SKNode()
    
    //create shapes
    for _ in 0...100 {
        let shape = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: CGFloat.random(in:1...30))
        shape.position.x = CGFloat.random(in: 0..<frame.width)
        shape.position.y = CGFloat.random(in: 0..<frame.height)
        container.addChild(shape)
    }
    
    //render container to a single texture
    let texture:SKTexture? = self.view?.texture(from:container)
    return texture
}
```

assign this texture to a sprite node and you will have 1 draw call. it's expensive to make the render, but cheaper in the long run if you reduce many graphical nodes to one. note: since the resulting texture is not atlased, this 1 call will never be batched with others.

Comment: Thanks, i´m gonna try this when im back Home. I´ll let you know how it went!